# In Binary Tree, find how many grandfathers have only two or three grandchildrens

Tags: c++, c, binary-tree

```
                                   8
                                /      \
                              4         12
                             / \         / \
                           3    6       2   1
                          / \   / \    /   / \
                         7  10 13 15  5   9  11
                                             /
                                            14
```

I need to find the grandfathers of a tree, in this exemple I have only one grandfather, number 12 (I need that he has only two or three grandchildren) .

This is what I tried so far:

```
int T(struct node * tree){
    int t = 0;
    if (tree == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (tree->left && tree->right)
    {    //In this case i check if we NOT have all the four grandchildrens.
        if (!((tree->left->left) && (tree->left->right) && (tree->right->left) && (tree->right->right)))
        {
            t =  1 + T(tree->left) + T(tree->right);
            T(tree->left);
            T(tree->right);

        }
        else
       {
            T(tree->left);
            T(tree->right);
        }

    }

    return t;

}
```

Unfortunately it does not work... Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You're doing quite a few recursive calls where you ignore the return value.

Comment: How balanced is the tree?  Is it possible to have only one child but two grandchildren?  If so, you need extra code for that case (beyond fixing the bug in what you have).

Comment: Number 1 have only one grandchild i need that he have two or three

Comment: Yes it possible , one child two grandchildren , this is a Binary Tree

Comment: You could fix your design to cover all the odd cases (such as one child but two grandchildren) and to correctly accumulate the recursive returns.  But it is simpler to do it all a very different way, which I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One efficient approach is to recursively return a pair of results.  There are more elegant ways to return a pair in C++, but I'll use the old kludgy C way of returning one output through an input by pointer:

```
int T2(struct node * tree, int* child_count)
{
    int t = 0;  // Count the things we are supposed to count
    int g = 0;  // Count grandchildren of the current node
    if (tree == NULL)
        return 0;
    if ( tree->left )
    {
       ++ *child_count;
       t += T2( tree->left, &g );
    }
    if ( tree->right )
    {
       ++ *child_count;
       t += T2( tree->right, &g );
    }
    if ( g==2 || g==3 )
       ++t;
    return t; 
}

int T(struct node * tree) {int dummy; return T2(tree, &dummy); }
```

The function does two things together.  The simple job is it helps count its parent's grandchildren by incrementing `*child_count`, and it also recursively does the main job by accumulating in `t`.

---

The following way might be easier to understand, but is less elegant:

```
int T(struct node * tree)
{
    struct node *c;
    int t = 0;  // Count the things we are supposed to count
    int g = 0;  // Count grandchildren of the current node
    if (tree == NULL)
        return 0;
    if ( (c=tree->left) != NULL )
    {
       g += (c->left != NULL) + (c->right != NULL);
       t += T( c );
    }
    if ( (c=tree->right) != NULL )
    {
       g += (c->left != NULL) + (c->right != NULL);
       t += T( c );
    }
    if ( g==2 || g==3 )
       ++t;
    return t; 
}
```

Comment: You can show me please how i do what you post without a pointer int* child_count and just int child_count

Comment: Why?  Are you programming in C or in C++ and what rule do you have that prohibit using an `int*`?

Comment: Oh ok  you write +t after if ( g==2 || g==3 ) instead of ++t

Comment: Sorry, I caught and fixed that typo a few minutes earlier, but you saw it before I fixed it.

Comment: It's ok , Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This becomes easier if you introduce a couple of child-counting functions, one that counts children and one that counts grandchildren:

```
int children(node* tree)
{
   if (!tree)
   {
      return 0;
   }
   int count = 0;
   if (tree->left)
   {
      count += 1;
   }
   if (tree->right)
   {
      count += 1;
   }
   return count;
}

int grandchildren(node* tree)
{
   if (!tree)
   {
      return 0;
   }
   return children(tree->left) + children(tree->right);
}

int grandparents(node* tree)
{
   if (!tree)
   {
      return 0;
   }
   int count = grandchildren(tree);
   if (count == 2 || count == 3)
   {
       return 1 + grandparents(tree->left) + grandparents(tree->right);
   }
   else
   {
       return grandparents(tree->left) + grandparents(tree->right);
   }
}
```