# how to use permutations for binary tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I don't understand why my code is printing the string double.

```
void find_first_index(char* str,char*strcopy_0, char* strcopy_1){
   char* find_x;

   find_x = strchr(str,'x');
   //set x equals to 0
   *find_x='0';
   //call recursive
   strcpy(strcopy_0, str);

   *find_x = '1';
   strcpy(strcopy_1,str);

}
void binary_permute(char* str){

    char strcopy_0[100];
    char strcopy_1[100];

    //base case //if no x exists in str
    if(strchr(str, 'x') == NULL){
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }

    //if count is not zero
    else{
        //we need to loop through the string again
        find_first_index(str, strcopy_0, strcopy_1);
        binary_permute(strcopy_0);
        binary_permute(strcopy_1);
        printf("%s\n", strcopy_0);
        printf("%s\n", strcopy_1);


    }

}
```

an input of 0x0x0 will result in

> 00000
>
> 00010
>
> 00000
>
> 00010
>
> 01000
>
> 01010
>
> 01000
>
> 01010

instead of just printing it once

> 00000
>
> 00010
>
> 01000
>
> 01010

My best guest is that I make too much call with two recursions in a function.
Is there any other way to do this that works?

Comment: Try using a debugger and step through the code line by line. When you come to the recursive calls step into those.

Comment: You also have a possible and very subtle bug waiting to happen: You can attempt to modify a constant string (like a string literal, which is read-only). Take a closer look at the `find_first_index` function, and think about the case when `str` is pointing to a string literal.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how. I know where I made a mistake but I don't know how to fix it, finding another solution to the problem. Can you help me

Comment: Halphh!! desperate

Comment: Every `if(strchr(str, 'x') == NULL){` prints the string, returns and the string gets printed another time.

Comment: but it doesn't matter right? does it have an impact with the recursion?

Comment: Let find_first_index return whether it changed anything and call binary_permute only `if(find_first_index(...)`. Then you can remove the block `if(strchr(str, 'x') == NULL){`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Binary Tree, find how many grandfathers have only two or three grandchildrens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483586/in-binary-tree-find-how-many-grandfathers-have-only-two-or-three-grandchildrens)